# Add class to image_tag in Rails with IF statement

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image

I have a image tag setup for a blog that if an image has been attached to the blog then display the image.

```
<%= image_tag blog.image_url(:thumb) if blog.image? %>
```

I am trying to add a class to this image tag so that I can use CSS to edit it.  I have tried a few different ways to add the class but none seem to work.

```
<%= image_tag blog.image_url(:thumb) if blog.image?, :class => "img" %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag (blog.image_url(:thumb), :class => "img") if blog.image? %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag (blog.image_url(:thumb) if blog.image?), :class => "img" %>
```

does anyone know how to add a class to this type of statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= image_tag(blog.image_url(:thumb), class: 'img') if blog.image? %>
```

I use `<%= image_tag(@user.image_url, size: 50, class: 'gravatar') if @user.image_url? %>` in my project, and it works.